# cast error when inflating a serialized object on server side

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

I am trying to send a serialized Java object from a client to a server via socket, but there is a cast error on the server side and I can't figure out why.
The Class being serialized is below. (I am using Eclipse, and this class is in both the client 
package and the server package.)

```
package client; //it is "package server;" on server side

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Simple implements Serializable {
    public String msg;
    public Simple(){
        msg = "simple";
    }
}
```

on client side, I did:

```
Simple obj = new Simple();
Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, portNum);
ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
objOut.writeObject(obj);
objOut.flush();
objOut.close();
```

on the server side, I did:

```
//already accepted clientSocket
ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
Simple anObj = (Simple) objIn.readObject();
System.out.println("from server: " + anObj.msg);
objIn.close();
clientSocket.close();
```

However, I got the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: client.Simple cannot be cast to server.Simple at server.Server.main
```

I tried something similar with the Server and Client in a single package, and both the serialization and inflation worked. I would really appreciate it if you can help me find out why it doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put; to avoid two types in different namespaces from colliding, *the package name is a part of the type name*.

What happens is that the client serializes a `client.Simple`, which the server also deserializes as a `client.Simple`. Then you proceed by casting it to a `server.Simple`, which is an entirely different type.

It can be shown by doing;

```
ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
Object anObj = objIn.readObject();
System.out.println(anObj);               // Output "client.Simple@39617189"
obj = (server.Simple)anObj;              // Throws ClassCastException
```

The code shows that the server *knows* that the type of the deserialized object is `client.Simple`, and it simply can't cast it to the separate type `server.Simple`.

Answer (score 0):

//it is "package server;" on server side
So do you have two different Simple classes? What I mean is, Are you declaring the "Simple" class twice under two different package so they are different and can not be cat. Have only one class. You can use this [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/sockets/).

Answer (score 0):

- What you are serializing and sending is `class client.simple`
- But on the received object you are trying to typecast it to a different class `class server.simple`
- These are two different classes and hence you are getting the exception.
- Ensure that server has access to same class `client.simple` which is used for serialization.